# Maitreya 7 error: linked to "config directory /usr/share/maitreya6/"

Tags: linux, debian, command-line

I am truing to run `maitreya_textclient` (an application to list astrological information in text mode) and I get the following error:

```
WARN: datadir does not exist
Fatal error: cannot open Yoga config directory /usr/share/maitreya6/../xml/yogas
```

On **Debian "testing"** repository `Maitreya` comes as version: `7.0.7-1+b1`

so it seems the textclient points to a wrong directory, since I got `/usr/share/maitreya7/` on my system.

Does anyone on here know how and where to fix this?
The GUI Application runs without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although posting a bug report would be best, in the interim you could try fixing up the broken directory paths to point the missing version 6 directory at the version 7 one that exists

```
cd /usr/share
ln -s maitreya7 maitreya6
```

I can't test this, though, so I don't know if you'll find your `yogas` in there at the right place.

Comment: yes found the `yogas` :-) Thanks again!